# React curly brace in variable declaration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently followed a react tutorial to create a template project and have since been modifying code to fit my needs. In particular, there was this piece of code on a component that was passed a parameter called `label`.

```
render() {
  const { label } = this.props;
  ...
}
```

In this example, I returned a JSON object from a controller and passed it to this component using a parameter named `rune`. A property of the `rune` JSON is "name", and I wanted to assign the name to a variable called `label. One thing that gave me trouble was the following:

```
render() {
  console.log("Prop.runes.name: " + this.props.rune.name);
  const { label } = this.props.rune.name;
  console.log("Label: " + label);
  ...
}
```

The first `console.log(...)` outputs the name correctly. However, the second log was undefined. After some trial and error, I found that if I removed the curly braces from my `const` declaration the name resolved properly.

```
render() {
  const label = this.props.rune.name;
  ...
}
```

What were the curly braces originally doing? Is there a reason the tutorial initially had them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you ask here is not related to React actually, it is related to Javascript: [Destructuring assignment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

For objects, you can destruct a property like that:

```js
const obj = {
  name: "foo",
};

const { name } = obj;
console.log( name );

const name2 = obj.name;
console.log( name2 );
```

Above, both assignments are equal. First one is the shorthand of the second one.

For your example:

```
const { label } = this.props.rune.name;
```

Here, there is a `this.props.rune.name.label` property and you are destructing it from `this.props.rune.name`. This is equal to:

```
const label = this.props.rune.name.label;
```

not actually

```
const label = this.props.rune.name;
```

as you tried.

The related part of React with this syntax is we see it very frequently in React world. Like:

```
render() {
    const { foo, bar } = this.props;
    const { fizz, buzz } = this.state;
    return (
      <p>A {foo} goes to {bar} and orders a {fizz} without {buzz}</p>; 
    )   
}
```

or

```
const AComponent = ( { foo, bar } ) => (
  <p>{foo} loves {bar} in programming world.</p>
);
```

A caution. When dealing with nested properties to destruct being careful is important. Since as @Tyler Sebastian explained in the comments it is not `null` safe.

```
const data = { obj: { name : "foo"} };
const { obj: { name } } = data;
```

This is OK but if we have a typo there or if we try to use a property which does not exist at that time we get an `error` since we try to destruct a property from an `undefined` one.

```
const data = { obj: { name : "foo"} };
const { objx: { name } } = data;
```

This throws an error. Thanks to @Tyler Sebastian for the comment.

Comment: This was an excellent explanation, thank you. For anyone else who wants a deeper reading, nosleepfilipe's answer below has an excellent article on depth destructuring that was also very useful!

Comment: You are welcome. You will see destructuring syntax so frequently in React world. When used decently it is very useful. And yes, it is a nice article you mentioned here. There are lots of things we can do using destructuring, some of them are amazing for such a simple syntax :)

Comment: It's worth noting that it's _not_ null safe. `let x = { a: { b: { c: 1 } } }; let { a: { foo: { y } } } = x` will throw.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code

```
render() {
  console.log("Prop.runes.name: " + this.props.rune.name);
  const label = this.props.rune.name.label;
  console.log("Label: " + label);
  ...
}
```

You need to declare the variable label without the { }

The curly braces are for Destructuring

You can check here

[depth destructuring](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/)

Comment: Yes, I had figured that out! Per my question, I was curious what the curly braces were doing? I see them used elsewhere and they seem to work fine, so I would like to know what was different abut this case.

Comment: If you console.log( this.props ) you will see that will print a object with multiple keys. If you do let { varname } = this.props it will retrieve a copy of that variable from that object

Answer (score 1):

```
let {x} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40}
console.log(x) // undefined

let {b} = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40}
console.log(b) // 10

console.log(c) // Error: c is not defined
```

Essentially, `const { label } = this.props;` is undefined because the object `this.props` does not have the `label` property, hence it is unable to match it, as per my `x` example, but in the `b` example it does match a property, hence it assigned correctly.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is typically seen in React apps, e.g. import React, {Component} from 'react'