# React: Variable resets to default if another event function is run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have the following code in React:

```
let down = 0

const moveUp = e => {
//other code
let up = down - 300
}

const moveDown = e => {
//other code
down = down + 300
}

<Button onClick={moveUp} btntext="Up"/>
<Button onClick={moveDown} btntext="Down"/>
```

Down is the first button a user would click on, it increments the **down** variable by 300, so let's say we've incremented down 3 times, which would be 900.

The problem is, when we try to click on the **Up** button referencing the `moveUp` function, the **down** variable is now set back to it's default which is *0*, why does that happen, shouldn't the change to *900* be stored in memory?

I would really love some help here, there's clearly something I'm not understanding about Javascript events and variable scopes.

Comment: Have you tried storing `down` in state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379896/what-is-state-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

Try storing `down` as a state variable. Your component maybe getting rerendered somewhere causing `down` to initialize back to 0.

Updating that would be

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const [down, setDown] = useState(0)

const moveUp = e => {
    //other code
    setDown(down - 300)
}

const moveDown = e => {
    //other code
    setDown(down + 300)
}

<Button onClick={moveUp} btntext="Up"/>
<Button onClick={moveDown} btntext="Down"/>
```