# Render Component on Button Click

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to render a loading Spin while the fetch is running but the component is not rendering.

```
export const LoginStructure: React.FC<{ closeModal: any }> = ({ closeModal }) => {
let spinning: boolean;

...
return (
<>
  <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={() => spinning = true}>
     {spinning ? <Spin /> : <></>}
  </Button>
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've overlooked the most fundamental part of React in every React tutorial... *state*.  Just updating a variable doesn't trigger a component to re-render.  Updating state does:

```
const [spinning, setSpinning] = useState(false);

...

<Button htmlType="submit" onClick={() => setSpinning(true)}>
   {spinning ? <Spin /> : <></>}
</Button>
```

Comment: Just to add to the answer, you could check this question as well which explains the state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379896/what-is-state-in-react

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger a loading boolean state when the component is fetching something from the API, the best approach would be to first create a state with `useState` hook.

Then in your fetch logic, you should set the state to true, and after the fetch is done, set it back to false.

```
// ... code
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

async function getData() {
  setLoading(true);
  try {
    //... your fetch logic
  catch {
    //... error handling
  finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
}

return (
  <Button htmlType="submit" onClick={() => getData()}>
    {spinning ? <Spin /> : <></>}
  </Button>
)
```