# Error when assign multiple this.props properties to new variables once in Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have tried to assign multiple `this.props` properties at once in the Child Component:

```
const {readings, wantRead, read} = this.props;
```

When I tried to use `readings` as the props in the next child component, it seems just undefined and error out.

But here the weirdest stuff is if I first assign the `this.props` properties one by one like:

```
const readings = this.props.currentlyReading;
```

Then used the `readings` inside the next child component, it just works fine.

Not really sure what happened at first????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use Destructuring assignment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like you did:

```
const {readings, wantRead, read} = this.props;
```

What you need to put in between brackets (`{}`) is the name of the variable present in `this.props`, that you want to access.

So you need to use `currentlyReading` instead of `reading`:

```
const {currentlyReading, wantRead, read} = this.props;
```

source + explication : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52286807/6809926

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Really helpful!